# accessing list objects from different class C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

I am trying to workout to see how I can access list items from a different class and to update the same, I have my code below for clarification.

```
class list
{
    private List<Person> people;
    public List<Person> People
    {
       get { return people; }
       set { people = value; }
    }
}

public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    Person p = new Person();
    list l = new list();

    p.Name = textBox1.Text;
    p.Streetaddress = textBox2.Text;
    p.Email = textBox3.Text;
    p.Birthday = dateTimePicker1.Value;
    p.AdditionalNotes = textBox4.Text;

    l.People.Add(p);
    listView2.Items.Add(p.Name);
}
```

there is Person class which has instance variables Name, Streetaddress etc.

Getting an error

> Nullreference exception was unhandled

Please help me..

Comment: where is new keyword? u havent user new keyword for List<Person>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to instantiate the inner `List<Person>` when the List class is instantiated. Otherwise it will be null.

```
class list
{

   private List<Person> people = new List<Person>();
   public List<Person> People
   {
       get { return people; }
       set { people = value;}
   }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, sorry for these silly questions. I am still learning C# so.... Thank you..

Comment: Np raam030. I make the same mistake a lot, too. If you are in debug mode, you can also view the exception stack trace and it will often show you the line number of where the null reference exception occurred which can be very helpful. If this answer helped you, you can click the check mark under the number to accept it which will help future people find it easier.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you have defined a property **People** in class **list** but have not initialized it. Just initialize it in the constructor of **list** class.

Can you try:

```
class list
    {

       private List<Person> people;
       public List<Person> People
       {
           get { return people; }
           private set { people = value;}
       }

       public list()
       {
         people = new List<Person>();
       }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks friend, as above comment I was not instantiating list in my class now its sorted.. Thanks